# How to create an alias for a printer?

Tags: printing

I'm using a network printer that has a very long name ("HP_LaserJet_...") witha full description of the printer. I want to create an alias (e.g. "lp1") to use when I have to specify the printer name, e.g. on a command line. Is there a way to create an alias?

It seems that one option is to change the printer name to "pr1" using system-config-printer. What files will be changed if I do this? If something goes wrong I want to be able to back out of the change? Is there a way to keep the original long name in a comment in printers.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser to to open the CUPS Admin interface `http://localhost:631/admin` and add a new printer, with the name you want. Read `man cupsenable`, `man lpadmin`, and do something like (from the command line):

```
cupsdisable HP_LaserJet_...
cupsenable lp1
# for systemwide setting
sudo lpadmin -d lp1
# or, for user settings
lpadmin -d lp1
```

Long ago, I did `sudo adduser $USER lp;sudo adduser $USER lpadmin` and logged out/in. You may have to do this too, to make CUPS commands easier.

Comment: Thanks.I am unclear what the effect will be. I assume the cupsdisable command will disable use of the original name, so would have the same effect as renaming the printer.

Comment: Read `man cupsdisable`. In general, if you're given a command to execute (e.g. `cupsdisable`), by an Internet Stranger, your first step should always be `man cupsdisable`.

Comment: I did read the man page, which says disabling the printer means it will stop the printer. If the printer will no longer accept jobs, that seems equivalent to it not existing. So the old name won't work anymore and the new one will, which has the same effect as a rename. My goal with an alias is to be able to use both names.

Comment: You can skip the `cupsdisable`. But you'll have two printers competing for 1 printer. I have not experimented with this and it isn't an alias.